# Как оживить дату?

Tags: javascript, php

Здравствуй, ХешКод. Я бьюсь уже не знаю что сделать, есть innerHTML, и в php есть time() так вот я загоняю time() в переменную, и перевожу в нормальный вид, но нужно чтобы эта дата сама обновлялась каждую секунду, я пробовал innerHTML использовать, но у меня с ним ничего не получается.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
  function timer(){
  var obj=document.getElementById('divid');  
  obj.innerHTML = "<?=$datenext?>";
  }   
</script>

<?php
 $datenext = date("G:i:s", $res["datenext"] - time());
 echo "<div id = 'divid'>$datenext</div>";
?>
```

Но код не работает, можете помочь с реализацией, пожалуйста?

Comment: пфф... что-то вы перемудрили, в `javascript` вообще-то `setInterval` и таймаут есть. Не хочу код писать, хочу чтоб вы выучили.

Comment: Я это уже пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: @Angus у меня такое впечатление что вы даже понятие не имеете о работе веб...  
Сначала PHP вставляет значения всех переменных и отсылает результат, а потом исполняется JS и всё остальное...  
Вы хоть бы исходный код в браузере ради интереса посмотрели :)

Comment: Что вообще должно получиться в результате этого? Без понимания того, чего ты хочешь, тут никто не ответит

Comment: Есть допустим 2 часа, и идёт обратный отсчет до 0:00:00 и как это время настанет, перезагрузить страницу, вот и всё.

Comment: PHP не знаю если скажете что содержится $datenext я помогу...

Comment: оно содержии дату типа time() * 24 * 3600

Comment: а именно? "количество миллисекунд прошедших с 1 января 1971"? Например конкретно назовите число

Comment: Да верно, вот пример: 1349153265

Comment: Вот, посмотрите...

Answer (score 2):

Во первых работа с датой в php и js отличается. И не в пользу последнего. Суть такая: можно даже без php

Функция вызывает себя саму через каждую секунду setTimeout(myfunction, 1000) (вроде 1000).

ну так достаньте ее. Будет что-то типа:

```
var mydate = $('#mydate').val();
mydate = Date.parse(mydate);

function mydate()  {
    mydate += 1;

    var date = new Date;
    date.setTime(mydate);
    //выводим
    //вызываем себя
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что мне не нужна текущая дата, мне нужна дата что стоит в БД

Comment: поправил код

Там смотрите, для js нужен формат даты несколько иной, но на стороне php это поправить не проблема

Comment: в php и js отличается. И не в пользу последнего??? может быть вы перепутали?

Comment: я говорю о работе с датами, а не о языках. В php намного удобней и формат менять и прочее и прочее.

Comment: @forum3 лично я другого мнения

btw - var? не, не слышал

Comment: @AlexWindHope не спорю. Может и я плохо готовлю. Но думаю для вопроса это не основная задача. "var" я не обязан писать готовый код, я пишу чтобы показать как можно.

Comment: > "var" я не обязан писать

вы не из Индии случайно?

Comment: Я уже отписал, что не должен писать полностью готовый код. Отсутствие "var" не критично, можете написать готовый код сами, если вы считаете это критичным. Думаю Angus123 не будет против.
На ваш вопрос об Индии я думаю вы знаете ответ.

Comment: @forum3 - отсутствие "var" не критично???

познать многое предстоит тебе юный подаван

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>FreeLance</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var date, interval, element;
        function decreaseTimer(){
            date -= 1000;
            element.innerHTML = "Осталось: " + (date / 1000) + " секунд.";
            if(date <= 1000){
                clearInterval(interval);
                location.reload();
            }
        }
        window.onload = function(){
            date = 1349153265;
            element = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
            interval = setInterval(decreaseTimer,1000);
        };

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```